# Create Ad and assign creative and placement

Tags: google-apps-script, double-click-advertising, dfareporting

I have a campaign in Campaign Manager.
Within the campaign is 1 placement and 1 creative (both 160x600 and active)

I want to create an Ad, assign the creative, and then assign the placement using Google Apps Script in Google Sheets.

I've built out the Ad Resource using the API Reference in Google Apps Script.
I can get it to create the Ad, if the ad is set to "inactive". However, none of the assignments are done.

When I try to create the Ad with it set to "Active", I get an error:

> **"API call to dfareporting.ads.insert failed with error: 12032 : An ad cannot be active unless it is assigned to at least one placement."**

Randomly I also get this sometimes:

> **"API call to dfareporting.ads.insert failed with error: 12058 : At least one active creative must be assigned to any active ad. Also, the creative must have "Include in rotation" set to "Yes" in your ad properties."**

***Code below:***

```
funtion foo() { 
   var startTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
  var endDate = new Date (new Date(startTime).getYear()+1, new Date(startTime).getMonth(), new Date(startTime).getDate());
  var endTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(endDate), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');

      var adResource = {
        "kind": "dfareporting#ad",
        "active": "true",
        "archived": "false",
        "campaignId": "23237909",
        "name": "testApiAd",
        "creativeRotation": {
          "creativeAssignments": {
            "active": "true",
            "creativeId": "121312158",//.toString(),
            "clickThroughUrl": {
              "defaultLandingPage": "true",
              //"type": "CREATIVE_ROTATION_TYPE_RANDOM",
              //"weightCalculationStrategy": "WEIGHT_STRATEGY_EQUAL"
            }
          }
        },
        "deliverySchedule": {
          "impressionRatio": "1",
          "priority": "AD_PRIORITY_15",
          "hardCutoff": "false"
        },
        "endTime": endTime,
        "startTime": startTime,
        "type": "AD_SERVING_STANDARD_AD",
        "placementAssignments": {
          "active": "true",
          "placementId": "256185010",//.toString(),
          //"sslRequired": "true"
        }
      }

      var newAd = DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert(adResource, profileID);
  return newAd;
}
```

Is there something I'm not understanding? Or missing completely?
According the API Reference, it should be working but I can't figure out why it's not.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Ads with `active` flag set to `true` should have at least one `placementAssignments` set.

**Solution**

Take a look at **type** of the `placementAssignments` (as well as `creativeAssignments`) property - it should be a **list** (meaning that the value should be an instance of `Array`) while you define it as `object`. Simply make both placement and creative elements of an `Array`:

```
"placementAssignments": [{
  "active": "true",
  "placementId": "256185010",//.toString(),
  //"sslRequired": "true"
}]

"creativeRotation": {
  "creativeAssignments": [{
    "active": "true",
    "creativeId": "121312158",//.toString(),
    "clickThroughUrl": {
      "defaultLandingPage": "true",
      //"type": "CREATIVE_ROTATION_TYPE_RANDOM",
      //"weightCalculationStrategy": "WEIGHT_STRATEGY_EQUAL"
    }
  }]
 }
```

**Reference**

1. `ad` resource [overview](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/v3.2/ads);

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thanks for the help. Can't believe I missed something so obvious. It's always the simple things everyone forgets...

Comment: Hi @RajivAhmed, no worries, that happens quite a lot :) [in fact, this is one of the more common things to forget about]